# Rails console login fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, fedora

i get the following errors when i try to open the rails console:

```
$ rails console
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- minitest/unit (LoadError)
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /usr/share/ruby/test/unit/assertions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /usr/share/ruby/test/unit/testcase.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/console/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:304:in `initialize_console'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:152:in `load_console'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I use Fedora 17. I have installed Ruby and gem via yum and then rails via gem.

UPDATE: 
My installed gems, maybe there are some gems in my gemset missing or i have the false version of it.

```
$ gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.13)
actionpack (3.2.13)
activemodel (3.2.13)
activerecord (3.2.13)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (3.2.13)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.4)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.2.1)
json (1.7.7)
mail (2.5.3)
mime-types (1.22)
minitest (4.7.0)
multi_json (1.7.2)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.13)
railties (3.2.13)
rake (10.0.4)
rdoc (3.12.2)
sass (3.2.7)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
sprockets (2.2.2)
thor (0.18.1)
tilt (1.3.6)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (1.3.0)
```

Comment: Try install the `minitest` gem: `$ gem install minitest`.

Comment: I tried it, the error remains.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same gemset?

Comment: I have updated my question and added my gemset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i have solved the problem via manually installing ruby 2.0.0 and removing ruby 1.9.3 that i have installed via yum.

Answer (score 0):

Try by running:

```
script/rails console
```

and let us know what happens, otherwise you can also try

```
bundle exec script/rails console
```

Answer (score 0):

It's odd to be loading tests in the console... the minitest gem is probably only included in the test group and not available in the development environment.   Adding the gem to the development group would probably work, but that's treating a symptom, not the cause.

Somehow, maybe in a irbrc file, you are including test libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'test-unit'
end
```

and running

```
bundle
```

fixed my issue.

In your case you might want to include 'minitest'